# iText PdfCopy makes file larger and larger

Tags: java, arrays, itext

I'm attempting to merge multiple byte arrays to a single PDF and have that working, but it seems that the file grows larger and larger when it should just replace the file.  It also seems that the file is not closing correctly.  I don't know if I am missing a list in the merge logic, but that's the only place I could think it would be.

```
public class MergePDF {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MergePDF.class);

    private static ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    public static byte[] mergePDF (List<byte[]> pdfList) {

        try {
            Document PDFCombo = new Document();
            PdfSmartCopy copyCombo = new PdfSmartCopy(PDFCombo, baos);
            PDFCombo.open();
            PdfReader readInputPdf = null;
            int num_of_pages = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdfList.size(); i++) {
                readInputPdf = new PdfReader(pdfList.get(i));
                num_of_pages = readInputPdf.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int page = 0 ; page < num_of_pages;) {
                    copyCombo.addPage(copyCombo.getImportedPage(readInputPdf, ++page));
                }
            }
            PDFCombo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

I assume that I'm missing some sort of close in the process because when I save the file at a later time, it seems to tack on the size, but the PDF that I view doesn't add any additional pages.

Here is how I am saving the PDF off before sending it to a third party.  When sent it is a byte array.

```
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outMessage.getDocumentTitle());
        out.write(outMessage.getPayload());
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
    }
```

I have been told that there are multiple PDF Headers and EOF's in the bytearray that I'm sending over.

Comment: First allow me to tell you that this won't work: `PDFCombo.add(Chunk.NEWLINE);` in this context. Then there's your allegation *but it seems that the file grows larger and larger when it should just replace the file.* Replace which file? `PdfCopy` never replaces a file. You are building a new PDF by adding the pages of a series of other PDFs, why does it surprise you that this new PDF grows with every page you add? (Additionally, you might want to use `PdfSmartCopy` instead of `PdfCopy`.) I'm voting to close this question as "unclear".

Comment: I apologize for the lack of clarity.  When I meant it grows larger, I am saving the PDF in a later part of the code, and the file grows every time I save it instead of creating a new file.  The Original PDF is 66 kb and it adds 66kb each time I run this process.  When I run the process, it does not pull from the file I am saving off to, which is why I don't understand the file growing in size.

Comment: Either the target file also is among the sources in `pdfList` or your code saving to the target file *appends* instead of *overwriting*.

Comment: Using `PdfSmartCopy` instead of `PdfCopy` will make sure that shared resources aren't added redundantly. It would also be interesting to see how you are saving the return value of the `mergePDF()` method. @mkl's suggestion in combination with your mention of the "close" issue could indeed indicate that you're not replacing one set of bytes by another set of bytes, but that you are, in fact, adding a new set of bytes to the old set of bytes. We can't say anything about this, because we can't see how you are *replacing* the original file.

Comment: I have changed to PdfSmartyCopy and removed the chunk.Newline but I am still having the same problem.  I also included how I'm saving.  The PDF Byte arrays shouldn't be saved over.  One is pulled from a third party's file, and the other I create on the spot, so I wouldn't be pulling them from old information. Please let me know if I missed something that you were looking for.

Comment: Your `ByteArrayOutputStream` is a static member variable and you don't obviously reset it at the start of `mergePDF`. If you really don't reset it anywhere, you append result after result in it.

Comment: Aha, now I see it. This is yet another example of using bad coding habits, and then blaming iText for the error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @mkl's comment, it turns out that this was indeed true:

> @mkl's suggestion in combination with your mention of the "close"
>   issue could indeed indicate that you're not replacing one set of bytes
>   by another set of bytes, but that you are, in fact, adding a new set
>   of bytes to the old set of bytes.

This is how to solve the problem:

```
public class MergePDF {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(MergePDF.class);

    public static byte[] mergePDF (List<byte[]> pdfList) {

        try {
            Document PDFCombo = new Document();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            PdfSmartCopy copyCombo = new PdfSmartCopy(PDFCombo, baos);
            PDFCombo.open();
            PdfReader readInputPdf = null;
            int num_of_pages = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < pdfList.size(); i++) {
                readInputPdf = new PdfReader(pdfList.get(i));
                num_of_pages = readInputPdf.getNumberOfPages();
                for (int page = 0 ; page < num_of_pages;) {
                    copyCombo.addPage(copyCombo.getImportedPage(readInputPdf, ++page));
                }
            }
            PDFCombo.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e);
        }

        return baos.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Now you probably understand why the person teaching you how to code explained that using `static` variables is a bad idea in most cases.